# change default page in cpanel

Tags: cpanel

What do I need to do to change the default page in cpanel?

Comment: Are you root or reseller of Cpanel account? Ask for default page show or content of default page?  The best answers are for the best questions

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Update or create **.htaccess** file in the **public_html** folder and make the following content..

```
DirectoryIndex index.php home.php
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are referring to the default apache cPanel page then you will need whm access for that

WHM >> Main >> Account Functions >> Web Template Editor

Here you can change the default page, suspended page etc.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are referring to the default page when an account is created, this is easily done by creating an index.html or .php page within your /etc/skel folder (assuming you have a VPS or dedicated server).

There is a setting within WHM that allows for it in case you are not CLI savvy.

Hope this helps, sorry for the delayed response, but I'm new and trying to build my rep up!

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom branded login pages for cPAnel and WHM by using the advanced branding features of cPanel.  cPanel also supports custom login pages for each reseller's accounts.  Linked Below is the documentation.

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/CustomBrandedLoginPages

Answer (score 0):

how to create cpanel default page for hosting domains.

create default html page and upload the files in Skeleton Directory on cpanel root domain.

http://www.motherhost.in/members/knowledgebase/22/how-to-change-default-page-in-cpanel.html

The skeleton directory ( Skeleton Directory: A directory that defines what files and subdirectories new accounts will have by default. When the account is created, the new user’s account will contain an exact copy of the skeleton directory.) exists to let you easily copy the same files into every new account’s public_html and public_ftp directories when the account is created.

Keep in mind that:

```
When a visitor accesses http://example.com, he will see the contents of example.com 's public_html directory.
When a visitor accesses http://example.com/subdirectory, he will see the contents of public_html/subdirectory.
Contents of the public_ftp directory are available for anonymous FTP users to download.
```

This WHM feature simply states the location of the skeleton directory (/root/cpanel3-skel).

To set up your skeleton directory:

```
These files will be accessible to the new user via an FTP client.
Decide what kind of default setup you would like your new users to have.
Place the appropriate subdirectories and HTML files in /root/cpanel3-skel/public_html.
    These files will be copied to new accounts’ public_html directories when accounts are created.
Place the appropriate FTP-related files in /root/cpanel3-skel/public_ftp.
    These files will be accessible to the new user via an FTP client.
```